# What is the most efficient way to concatenate files of different compression types in a bash script?

Tags: bash, cat, built-in

I have come across this need several times now and I am surprised how hard it has been for me to find a "best" method for concatenating files of different compression types.

For instance, I have a directory with files `content1`, `content2.bz2`, and `content3.gz`. If I want to perform the same operation on all the files I have to first check what compression they are to decompress them correctly, decompress it, then perform my operation.

I have since written a script to handle the concatenation in a "smart" way.

```
#! /bin/bash
# Smart Cat
# usage smcat <file|file*>

for file in $@; do
    end=${file##*.}
    if [[ $end == 'bz2' ]] ; then
        bzcat $file
    elif [[ $end == 'gz' ]] ; then
        gzcat $file
    else
        cat $file
    fi
done
```

It just seems silly there isn't a built in way to handle all the different compression types. Or is there, and I have yet to find it? Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You might also want to see if http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html handles all the formats you want. It's available on my Ubuntu system as the `unar` package.

Comment: Fun fact: People have tried creating the One True Decompressor. Gzip handled the different formats at the time; `gzip`, `compress` and `pack`. Such efforts hardly ever work on Unix though, and apart from more and less serious efforts like your script, the only convention that stuck was using no arguments for compression and `-d` for decompression, thus allowing compressors to be used interchangeably (like for `tar -I`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use GNU Tar's Auto-Compress Flag

If you're mostly dealing with tarballs, you can solve part of your problem with GNU tar's auto-compress flag, which says:

```
 -a, --auto-compress
       use archive suffix to determine the compression program
```

This handles bz2 and gz extensions, but may fail you for more exotic things. For example:

```
tar xvfz "$filename"
```

will work on *somefile.tar.gz* and *somefile.tar.bz2* with equal facility.

### Use `/usr/bin/file` for Identification

The file utility will generally give you the correct file type with a little help from grep or a glob pattern. For example:

```
$ file foo*
foo:     ASCII text
foo.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k
foo.gz:  gzip compressed data, was "bar", from Unix, last modified: Fri Mar  8 17:33:48 2013
```

You could use a case statement to make short work of these files, either iterating over a file glob or over positional arguments with `"$@"`. Either way, this example should help:

```
for file in foo*; do
    case `file "$file"` in
        *ASCII*) cat   "$file" ;;
         *gzip*) zcat  "$file" ;;
          *bz2*) bzcat "$file" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I like the idea of using the file utility! Makes the loop a little more concise. @zzk had the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is not a single built in way to handle different compression type. If you don't want to rely on file extension to determine the compression type, you could use `file` command, e.g.

```
file test.bz2   
test.bz2: bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k
```

Comment: @CodeGnome mentioned the same idea! Thanks!